# Is it possible to copy/paste R regression summary to Excel without using functions?

Tags: r, excel

```
fit.iris.lm <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris)
summary(fit.iris.lm)
```

This gives us the following output:

[image]

I'm looking for a way to copy/paste the coefficients table from R console to Excel by highlighting the table and then Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V-ing it into Excel.

[image]

However, upon pasting it into Excel, all the columns are condensed into a single column:

[image]

I am looking for a way to copy/paste this output into Excel with all columns (Estimate, Std. Error) retained instead of condensed in one column and I am **specifically** looking for a way to do this ***without using any R functions for exporting tables*** (like `write_xlsx)` or any other similar functions - I just want to copy and paste it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't avoid using *any* function but if you just want something you can neatly paste you can use `broom::tidy()` to convert the values into a tibble and `clipr::write_clip()` to copy it to the clipboard.

```
library(broom)
library(clipr)
library(magrittr)

lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length + Petal.Width, iris) %>%
  tidy() %>%
  write_clip()
```

Pasted into Excel:

[image]

Comment: I regularly use the following code to put it into Excel:

`summary(fit.iris.lm)$coefficients %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  full_join(lm.beta(fit.iris.lm)$coefficients %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
 ` colnames<-`("Beta") %>% 
    rownames_to_column()) %>% 
  slice(-1) %>% 
  select(rowname, Estimate, Beta, Std..Error, t.value, Pr...t..) %>% 
 `colnames<-`(c("Predictor", "B", "Beta", "SDB", "t", "p")) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(B:p), round, 3) %>% 
  write_excel_csv2("Stres_Step.csv")`

But was looking for a way to do it without coding. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You could also just clean this up on the Excel side. After you paste it in Excel, select the pasted text. On the "Data" tab on the ribbon, select "Text to Columns".

[image: Location of Text-to-Columns]

This will open a dialog box.  Leave it at "Fixed Width" and click "Next".

[image: Dialog box]

This should give you a preview of the way that it will divide the columns. For your example,  it was fine so just click "Finish".

You get the result I think you want.

[image: Final result]